# What causes a SocketException: Socket closed?

Tags: java, networking

What are the possible reasons I can get a "Socket closed" SocketException apart from me calling close() on the socket?

I'm using ice4j in my library and one of the connectors throws an `SocketException: Socket closed` exception when attempting to read from it. The underlying socket is a DatagramSocket which internally uses a DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.

When I use a debugger to print a statement each time a socket get's created, the socket closed exception is thrown (connector died) or a socket got closed (Logging DatagramSocket close call and even DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl close call) I see the socket being created, the exception being thrown and the socket only being closed afterwards. (debugger also shows the socket as not closed at the point the exception is thrown.

```
New ice udp socket: null    27816247
New ice udp socket: /192.168.178.20    4527382
New ice udp socket: /192.168.178.20    20777338
...
Connector died 20777338  //Socket closed exception got thrown
Close udp socket /192.168.178.20   20777338  //Connector caused another close call to handle the exception
Close udp socket /192.168.178.20   20777338
...
```

Comment: Maybe ice4j doing that when it detects that the other side isn't responding? A UDP socket can't be closed from the other side AFAIK so it should be something on your system that does that. Maybe you're missing some event handling.

Comment: It isn't. This happens millisceonds after starting connectivity checks. It closes the socket bound to the local subnet address, which is then also used to test srflx/relay candidates/communicate with the TURN server which then breaks down aswell. I'm not quite sure how ice4j would be able to close the socket without my debugger catching it :) .